# How to combine media queries with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a problem while using media queries. I have a web page which is sliced into 3 parts. Depending on the screen resolution or available width the regions will be shown. For example on resolutions with less than or equals to 1024, only 2 of 3 regions are shown. On resolutions less than or equals to 480, only 1 of 3 regions is shown. Resolutions greater than 1024, all three regions are shown. Each part can be expanded and collapsed again.

Sample demo can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/44QB3/

I wrote this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Inventory details</title>
        <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .container {
            padding-top: 50px;
            position: relative;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0px 10px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .leftPanel {
            width: 34%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-right: 20px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        .centerPanel {
            width: calc(33% - 20px);
            width: -webkit-calc(33% - 20px);
            width: -moz-calc(33% - 20px);
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-right: 20px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        .rightPanel {
            width: calc(33% - 20px);
            width: -webkit-calc(33% - 20px);
            width: -moz-calc(33% - 20px);
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .headerPanel-Style {
            height: 25px;
            padding: 5px 0px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcece;
        }
        .bodyPanel-Style {
            height: calc(100% - 36px);
            height: -webkit-calc(100% - 36px);
            height: -moz-calc(100% - 36px);
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        .panel-Sidebar {
            width: 20px;
            height: 100%;
            background: #cfcece;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            display: none;
        }
        .toggleButton {
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            border: 1px solid #cfcece;
            background: white;
            cursor: pointer; 
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            .leftPanel {
                width: 60%;
            }
            .centerPanel {
                margin-right: 10px;
                width: calc(40% - 50px);
                width: -webkit-calc(40% - 50px);
                width: -moz-calc(40% - 50px);
            }
            .rightPanel {
                width: 20px;
            }
            .rightPanel .panel-Header {
                display: none;
            }
            .rightPanel .panel-Body {
                display: none;
            }
            .rightPanel .panel-Sidebar {
                display: block;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            .leftPanel {
                margin-right: 10px;
                width: calc(100% - 60px);
            }
            .centerPanel {
                width: 20px;
            }
            .centerPanel .panel-Header {
                display: none;
            }
            .centerPanel .panel-Body {
                display: none;
            }
            .centerPanel .panel-Sidebar {
                display: block;
            }
        }
        .leftPanel-Collapse {
            width: 20px;
        }
        .leftPanel-Header-Collapse {
            display: none;
        }
        .leftPanel-Body-Collapse {
            display: none;
        }
        .leftPanel-Sidebar-Show {
            display: block;
        }
        .centerPanel-Expand {
            width: calc(100% - 60px);
            width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
            width: -moz-calc(100% - 60px);
        }
        .centerPanel-Header-Expand {
            display: block;
        }
        .centerPanel-Body-Expand {
            display: block;
        }
        .centerPanel-Sidebar-Hide {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function init() {
            var centerToggle = document.getElementsByClassName("centerPanel")[0].getElementsByClassName("panel-Sidebar")[0].getElementsByClassName("toggleButton")[0];
            centerToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
                var leftPanel = document.getElementsByClassName("leftPanel")[0];
                var leftPanelHeader = leftPanel.getElementsByClassName("panel-Header")[0];
                var leftPanelBody = leftPanel.getElementsByClassName("panel-Body")[0];
                var leftPanelSidebar = leftPanel.getElementsByClassName("panel-Sidebar")[0];
                leftPanel.setAttribute("class", leftPanel.getAttribute("class") + " leftPanel-Collapse");
                leftPanelHeader.setAttribute("class", leftPanelHeader.getAttribute("class") + " leftPanel-Header-Collapse");
                leftPanelBody.setAttribute("class", leftPanelBody.getAttribute("class") + " leftPanel-Body-Collapse");
                leftPanelSidebar.setAttribute("class", leftPanelSidebar.getAttribute("class") + " leftPanel-Sidebar-Show");

                var centerPanel = document.getElementsByClassName("centerPanel")[0];
                var centerPanelHeader = centerPanel.getElementsByClassName("panel-Header")[0];
                var centerPanelBody = centerPanel.getElementsByClassName("panel-Body")[0];
                var centerPanelSidebar = centerPanel.getElementsByClassName("panel-Sidebar")[0];
                centerPanel.setAttribute("class", centerPanel.getAttribute("class") + " centerPanel-Expand");
                centerPanelHeader.setAttribute("class", centerPanelHeader.getAttribute("class").replace("panel-Header", "") + " centerPanel-Header-Expand");
                centerPanelBody.setAttribute("class", centerPanelBody.getAttribute("class").replace("panel-Body", "") + " centerPanel-Body-Expand");
                centerPanelSidebar.setAttribute("class", centerPanelSidebar.getAttribute("class").replace("panel-Sidebar", "") + " centerPanel-Sidebar-Hide");
            }, false);
        }
        //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="leftPanel">
                <div class="headerPanel-Style panel-Header">
                    Left Panel
                </div>
                <div class="bodyPanel-Style panel-Body">
                </div>
                <div class="panel-Sidebar">
                    <div class="toggleButton">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="centerPanel">
                <div class="headerPanel-Style panel-Header">
                    Center Panel
                </div>
                <div class="bodyPanel-Style panel-Body">
                </div>
                <div class="panel-Sidebar">
                    <div class="toggleButton">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightPanel">
                <div class="headerPanel-Style panel-Header">
                    Right Panel
                </div>
                <div class="bodyPanel-Style panel-Body">
                </div>
                <div class="panel-Sidebar">
                    <div class="toggleButton">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Its working fine when I resize the browser. But when I start expanding and collapsinf the problem comes. Suppose I collapsed a region, say the first region, and then I start expanding the window little bit, say 1px to 2px. Now the panels behave in unexpected manner.

What I want to achieve is to expand collapse panels while using media queires. I dont want to use jquery and similar apis. They are forbidden to use.

Comment: Just a thought: do you think your user will resize his browser? I know myself when I develop a responsive website that I tend to resize to see if it works, but I often realise that my users will never resize their browser when using my site, or when they do they will go to a new page, correcting the formatting. I can understand that you want to fix this if you are developing an app, but otherwise I think this is trivial.

Comment: @Fred This isn't trivial, its hard to explain to Boss / Client. If the Boss does the resizing & results are not as expected, then you can imagine what will happen.

Comment: @Fred As a user I want to resize my window. Infact even now I resized my browser. I do it always.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya `Now the panels behave in unexpected manner.`Did you mean, the third panel is going down?

Comment: Can less css solve my problem? Because we are using less css. I have no idea what less css is. Thats why I am asking this

Comment: I've updated your fiddle. Can you check, Is that what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/44QB3/1/

Comment: Thank you Surjith. This is one of many I want to achieve. I will check your changes and will try my best to apply the changes in rest of the areas. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

why use javascript....something like below would also solve,wouldn't it??

```
 @media only screen 
        and (max-width : 1024px) {
         .div_show_1024{
            display:block; 
          }
         .div_hide_1024{
          display:none; 
          }
        }

    @media only screen 
        and (max-width : 480px) {
         .div_show_480{
            display:block; 
          }
         .div_hide_480{
          display:none; 
          }
        }
```

Now all you have to do is that assign these classes to the respective divs!!!

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to tell. My code is working fine when resizing the browser window, zooming in and zooming out. The problem comes when I want to collapse and expand the browser.

Comment: idea is, to use `media-queries` for what they are supposed to do...an what do you mean by **collapse and expand the browser**??

Comment: Oops! Sory thats a typing mistake. The problem comes when expanding and collapsing the panels.

Comment: sorry...i dont think m able to get your *panel* problem, coz your diddle looks just fine to me!! :(

Comment: set the fiddle result panel to match the width of a mobile. Then click on top of the second panel. This will collapse first panel and expand second panel. Now start expanding the width of the result and then you will see the problem. The same kind of problems arise when I start implementing collapse/expanding for rest of the panels.

Comment: ok...i undertsand your problem now.....unfortunately m not very good with JS thing...i see your divs are floating down instead of getting hidden....that's exactly what my quoted CSS is supposed to do... **for e.g** , if you add `div_hide_480` class to any div, it will get hidden once the viewport width goes below 480px...!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var TO = false;
    var resizeEvent = 'onorientationchange' in window ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize';
    $(window).bind(resizeEvent, function() {
        TO && clearTimeout(TO);
        TO = setTimeout(resizeBody, 200);
    });
    function resizeBody(){
        var width = window.innerWidth || $(window).width();
      if(width<1024)
//some statments here;
    }
```